# Why is it a bad idea to manually wire OSGi services?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, declarative-services

In order to favor certain service implementations over others, I wrote a customizable version of [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) (adds priority and enabled/disabled flag to implementations via preference files for non-OSGi code).

The client was pleased and wanted the same customization for OSGi service implementations. 
The devised solution is based on calling [`getServiceReferences(Class<S> clazz, String filter)`](http://BundleContext.html#getServiceReferences(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) on [`BundleContext`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) and uses a `null` filter to retrieve all implementations.

Nevertheless, fiddling around with OSGi on such a low level leaves a bad taste. There's much boilerplate code (e.g. mandatory subtypes of [`BundleActivator`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html)) and the used approach will also hinder an smooth upgrade to declarative services and some point in time.

I also read about the [`SERVICE_RANKING`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#SERVICE_RANKING) property, but compared to the preference files from the approach above, it has the drawback that each implementation sets its own ranking property and it's not possible to change the ranking afterwards.

---

So my question is: What are good arguments against this low-level approach? Why should declarative services be used instead?

Comment: Thought about using `SERVICE_RANKING` together with a ranking policy, e.g. standard code has a ranking < 100, customer-specific code (which is more important) has a ranking > 1000. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the core OSGi is a dynamic environment. Bundles and services can come and go at every moment (theoretically). So the only way to cope with this environment is to react on changes compared to waiting for something to happen.

For example a declarative services component will come up once all its mandatory services are present and will vanish if one goes away.
A solution based on service loader or similar will actively get the services that are available if such a service is mandatory then you will have to block until it is available. This can easily lead to deadlocks in the application.

Of course in practice the application is normally not so dynamic. In most cases this only affects the startup of the application. So in many cases the blocking behaviour can work but it will produce an application that is inherently fragile.

On the other hand if you have the problem that your application needs to run inside and outside of OSGi then DS is problematic as it relies on OSGi to be present. 
Typical examples are Aapache CXF and Apache Camel. Both do not use DS and instead invented different abstractions for usage in OSGi and both sometimes have problems in OSGi exactly because of this. Still it would be difficult to improve this as they need to work outside of OSGi too.

Comment: So the main arguments are ease of deployment (including "hot swapping" of bundles)?

Comment: The argument is that a reactive approach like DS gives you a stable system behaviour. Manual wiring with blocking tends to make your system startup break when it reaches a certain complexity (e.g dead locks or timeouts).

Comment: Okay, and how would you favor certain service implementations over others, e.g. customer-specific implementations are favored over general code? Is there solution, that works via configuration files? Possibly without recompiling?

Comment: On DS you can use service.ranking property to auto choose a service. But the switch to the new service only works for greedy references. Another possibility is to use myRef.target in the config of the DS client component. It allows to specify which service to choose using the ldap filter syntax.